# chr() equivalent returning a bytes object, in py3k

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

Python 2.x has `chr()`, which converts a number in the range 0-255 to a byte string with one character with that numeric value, and `unichr()`, which converts a number in the range 0-0x10FFFF to a Unicode string with one character with that Unicode codepoint.  Python 3.x replaces `unichr()` with `chr()`, in keeping with its "Unicode strings are default" policy, but I can't find anything that does exactly what the old `chr()` did.  The `2to3` utility (from 2.6) leaves `chr` calls alone, which is not right in general :(

(This is for parsing and serializing a file format which is explicitly defined in terms of 8-bit bytes.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Consider using bytearray((255,)) which works the same in Python2 and Python3. In both Python generations the resulting bytearray-object can be converted to a bytes(obj) which is an alias for a str() in Python2 and real bytes() in Python3.

```
# Python2
>>> x = bytearray((32,33))
>>> x
bytearray(b' !')
>>> bytes(x)
' !'

# Python3
>>> x = bytearray((32,33))
>>> x
bytearray(b' !')
>>> bytes(x)
b' !'
```

Answer (score 57):

Try the following:

```
b = bytes([x])
```

For example:

```
>>> bytes([255])
b'\xff'
```

Comment: I get a little twitchy about throwing around scratch arrays but probably I shouldn't.  It does the job, anyway.

Comment: @Zack: You could use ``bytes((255, ))`` as a variation.

Comment: bytes((255,)) in Python2 will NOT give you b'\xff' ... it returns '(255,)' instead.

Comment: @GuidoDraheim2013: it is Python 3 code i.e., don't use `bytes([255])` on Python 2, use `chr(255)` there.

Comment: @malthe: `bytes((255, ))` is still creates a scratch array.

Answer (score 9):

Yet another alternative (Python 3.5+):

```
>>> b'%c' % 65
b'A'
```

Comment: Annoying that `b'{:c}'.format(65)` doesn't work as well, but thanks, this could be quite handy for the thing I originally wanted this for (and never got around to finishing).

Answer (score 8):

In case you want to write Python 2/3 compatible code, use [`six.int2byte`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.int2byte)

Comment: I don't see why that would be better than Guido's answer, particularly if I have no other need for `six`.

Comment: @zwol: For Python 3.2+, `int2byte = operator.methodcaller("to_bytes", 1, "big")`. According to the comment, this is about 2x faster than `bytes((...))`. Anyway, `int2byte(x)` looks better than `bytes(bytearray((x,)))` for me.

Comment: Speed is good, but in the thing that provoked the original question, *no dependencies outside the standard library* was an overriding concern.

Comment: `bytes` takes a `tuple` for a constructor directly, so you can just use `bytes((x,))`.  Only need to use `bytearray` if you want it to be mutable.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('B', 10)
b'\n'
>>> import functools
>>> bchr = functools.partial(struct.pack, 'B')
>>> bchr(10)
b'\n'
```

Comment: brilliant. `bchr` is readable and the implementation is efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest is:

```
int2byte = struct.Struct(">B").pack
```

(from six), followed by:

```
b'%c' % x
```

Both are even compatible with Python 2 and (surprisingly) faster there than `chr(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

simple replacement based on small range memoization (should work on 2 and 3), good performance on CPython and pypy

```
binchr = tuple([bytes(bytearray((b,))) for b in range(256)]).__getitem__

binchr(1) -> b'\x01'
```