# Python 3.4 with an older Python script for use in Blender, TypeErrors

Tags: python, string, typeerror, blender

I've converted a older Python script with the Python 2to3 tool to make it compatible with Blender. The script makes communication possible between Blender3D and a OMRON PLC. However after conversion the script gives the following error in the Blender 3D console:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

This occurs in the following lines:

```
def _send(self,  raw):
    self.sock.send( raw)
    #print ' Send:' + repr(raw)
def _recieve(self):
    pr = self.sock.recv(8)
    length = binstr2int( pr[4:8])
    r = pr + self.sock.recv( length)
    #print ' Recv:' + repr(r)
    return r
```

I've searched the problem using google and it seems its a problem that occurs when you convert or use an older script for Python 3+. Adding .encode() and .decode() to the objects where the problems occur has not helped either.

```
def _send(self,  raw):
    self.sock.send( raw.encode())
    #print ' Send:' + repr(raw)
def _recieve(self):
    pr = self.sock.recv(8).decode()
    length = binstr2int( pr[4:8])
    r = pr + self.sock.recv( length)
    #print ' Recv:' + repr(r)
    return r
```

This gives a different kind of error:

```
TypeError: can't convert 'bytes' to str implicitly
```

The script was not made by me, I'm simply using it for a school project to make communication possible between software (Blender3D) and hardware (PLC).

Help would be much appreciated, thanks.

I've put the converted version of the script [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v15jmexmrm8orgg/Convert.py)

Comment: A full backtrace would help. (btw: recieve looks like a typo)

Comment: The original version of the script can be found here (https://gitorious.org/omr/omr/commit/548633e768c2069fbf60ebbe79ed7f1d5c34e8aa#plcPyLib/omronTcpFins.py)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar to blender. Could you gimme some hint about how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: If you run the script I linked on my dropbox in Python 3.4 it will give the same errors. Blender uses Python 3+ for the coding of its 'game' environment.

Comment: But what's running on 192.168.106.123:9600, and how can I get that thing up and running? Without this, the program just raises an exception for not able to connect to the host.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, that command line opens a connection between the Python script and a OMRON Programmable logic computer using its communication protocol called FINS via a ethernet cable. I dont think its possible to reproduce. I will post the entire list of errors in the next comment.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Convert.py", line 340, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python34\Convert.py", line 303, in main
    plc.openFins('192.168.106.123', 9600)
  File "C:\Python34\Convert.py", line 252, in openFins
    self.plcType = self.conn.openn()
  File "C:\Python34\Convert.py", line 191, in openn
    self._send( c1.raw)
  File "C:\Python34\Convert.py", line 226, in _send
    self.sock.send( raw)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: Try: `self._send(bytes(c1.raw))` instead of `self._send( c1.raw)`

Comment: After adding bytes() 4 errors remain and the error message is different, thank you for your help so far. This is the remaining error list: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 340, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 303, in main
    plc.openFins('192.168.106.123', 9600)
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 252, in openFins
    self.plcType = self.conn.openn()
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 191, in openn
    self._send(bytes(c1.raw))
TypeError: string argument without an encoding

Comment: Hmm, you need to specify the encoding then. Try `bytes(..., 'utf-8')`

Comment: This results in a different error message, I will put the list in the next comment.

Comment: `File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 303, in main
    plc.openFins('192.168.106.123', 9600)
 File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 252, in openFins
    self.plcType = self.conn.openn()
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 192, in openn
    r1raw = self._recieve()
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 230, in _recieve
    length = binstr2int( pr[4:8])
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 35, in binstr2int
    n += ord(s[i]) * ( 1<<(8*( len(s)-i-1)))
    TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found`

Comment: So the first error seems solved already, that's good. The current one means ord() around your `s[i]` can be removed, since retrieving one element from `bytes` in Python 3.x is already a `int`

Comment: I believe the ord() calls are causing a problem in the program, I do not know how to remove them properly.

Comment: Like for `n += ord(s[i]) * ( 1<<(8*( len(s)-i-1)))`, just use `n += s[i] * ( 1<<(8*( len(s)-i-1)))` instead. i.e., remove the corresponding `ord(` and `)` around `s[i]`.

Comment: I have removed the ord() calls in the program. This is the error it gives me now `File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 35, in binstr2int
    n += s[i] * ( 1<<(8*( len(s)-i-1)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: Hmm, still raised from `self.plcType = self.conn.openn()`? If so, I want to know what type `s` exactly is (try to output `type(s)` before the problematic line)

Comment: `<class str>` is the output of `type(s)`.

Comment: Alright. So it seems your ord() calls are of mixed type of `bytes` and `str`. I'm updating my answer to give a quick & dirty workaround.

Comment: This seems to have fixed allot of problems, as I am getting more output in my shell. I have also encoded the self._send commands correctly. But there are still some errors remaining. I will put these in the next comment. The error I got is a `socket.timeout: timed out`

Comment: `File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 344, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 307, in main
    plc.openFins('192.168.106.123', 9600)
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 256, in openFins
    self.plcType = self.conn.openn()
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 214, in openn
    return self.doFinsCommand( MRC=0x05, SRC=0x01, cmdData = '\x00')[0:20]
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 220, in doFinsCommand
    r_raw = self._recieve()
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 233, in _recieve
    pr = self.sock.recv(8)`

Comment: Hrm, so you are sure that you don't get the socket.timeout errors when running the original script in Python 2? This is strange then.

Comment: I have just tried, it opens properly in Python 2 with no errors. I have found out the socket.timeout occurs when I change `self._send(c1.raw)` to `self._send(bytes(c1.raw, 'utf-8'))` under `openn`. However the error I get when I don't change `self._send(c1.raw)` is `File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix.py", line 230, in _send
    self.sock.send(raw)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: I'm not sure but, `utf-8` may not be the correct encoding for your data. Maybe try `ascii` instead?

Comment: I believe `utf-8` is correct, with ascii i get the following error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\x80' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Comment: This doesn't mean `utf-8` is correct though. On a second look, I think a better approach is to make the `FinsTCPframe` class and corresponding methods to use `bytes` internally. Try to add a "b" before any string constant, and remove the `bytes()` around c1.raw. For example, `'FINS'` => `b'FINS'`.

Comment: Hmm okay, like this? `self.rawTcpFrame = b'FINS'`, I've changed two off them in the class `FinsTCPframe`. This results in 2 new errors: `File "C:/Python34/ConvertStackfix1.py", line 193, in openn
    c1 = FinsTCPframe ( command = 0,  rawFinsCmd = int2str4(0))
  File "C:/Python34/ConvertStackfix1.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.rawTcpFrame += int2str4( 8 + len( commandFrame))    #frame length
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str` The errors in the `_send` and `_receive` commands are gone.

Comment: I mean all occurance of string constants. So `'ICF','RSV',...` becomes `b'ICF',b'RSV',...`, and even `''` becomes `b''`.

Comment: After I change all `'...'`, I get the same error.

Comment: Still get the timeout? This is weird. How about changing settimeout(1) to settimeout(0) (so it won't timeout at all)? (Though I don't think this is the problem, it's no harm to try)

Comment: No not the timeout, I'm getting the `Can't concat bytes to str` error.

Comment: And the backtrace? I need to know where the error is.

Comment: My bad: `File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix2b.py", line 344, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix2b.py", line 307, in main
    plc.openFins('192.168.106.123', 9600)
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix2b.py", line 256, in openFins
    self.plcType = self.conn.openn()
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix2b.py", line 193, in openn
    c1 = FinsTCPframe ( command = 0,  rawFinsCmd = int2str4(0))
  File "C:\Python34\ConvertStackfix2b.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.rawTcpFrame += 'int2str4( 8 + len( commandFrame))'    #frame length
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str`

Comment: So self.rawTcpFrame is still str. I'll try to read the code when I got home (out for dinner now). In the meantime, you can try to find where the variable got defined and modified, or paste the current version of the code somewhere.

Comment: Alright, enjoy your dinner. I will post a dropbox link shortly. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xm13v8azdlwumv3/ConvertStackfix2b.py

Comment: afaics, the `''` in intlist2str is missing a `b` prefix. Also the one in defining `commandFrame`.

Comment: Changed it, still the same.

Comment: This is what I found:
`self.rawTcpFrame = rawTcpFrame`

`r1raw = self._recieve()`
`r1 = FinsTCPframe( rawTcpFrame = r1raw )`

Comment: I got it, I'll update the answer to add a new workaround for `chr()`

Comment: Thanks I'll test this tommorow, I'm at home currently and I don't have access to a OMRON PLC. You will hear from me.

Comment: I think this solved the concat problem! But this creates a new problem as `bytes` doesn't support `.format()`, I've searched up some solutions as changing `.format()` to `.join()` but that gives an error also. It occurs in the following line: `str = b''.join([ b"{0}:{1} " .format(k, asm[k], ) for k in list(asm.keys())]` the error message: `'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'`

Comment: Try this: `b''.join([ k + b':' + asm[k] + b' ' for k in list(asm.keys())])`

Comment: A different error occurs: `str = b''.join([ k + b':' + asm[k] + b' ' for k in list(asm.keys())])
TypeError: can't concat bytes to int`

Comment: It seems `list(asm.keys())` is a set of integers.

Comment: Ah, I missed this. So `b''.join([ k + b':' + bytes(str(asm[k]), 'ascii') + b' ' for k in list(asm.keys())])`

Comment: Different error: `str = b''.join([ k + b':' + bytes(str(asm[k]), 'ascii') + b' ' for k in list(asm.keys())])`
`NameError: free variable 'str' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope`

Comment: internal function were overriden by the variable name :( try to remove the `str =` part and `return str`, just return the `b''...` part

Comment: Ah looks allot better haha but still an error: `in openn
print(("Sending: " + str( c1)))
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)`

Comment: Try to add `.encode('ascii')` after the `return b''...` line, and if it says ascii cannot encode, try "utf-8" instead

Comment: It tells me this with both ascii and utf-8: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: Ah, my fault, it should be `decode` :P

Comment: Haha, alright its fixed. Now I'm getting a error from somewhere else.. `File "C:/...", line 217, in openn
    return self.doFinsCommand( MRC=0x05, SRC=0x01, cmdData = '\x00')[0:20]
  File "C:/...", line 220, in doFinsCommand
    c = FinsTCPframe(MRC=MRC, SRC=SRC, cmdData = cmdData,  serverAdr=self.serverNode, clientAdr=self.clientNode,  cmdFlags = {'SID':self._nextSid} )
  File "C:/...", line 92, in __init__
    commandFlags[ self.FINScommandFlags.index( k)] = cmdFlags[k]
ValueError: 'SID' is not in list`

Comment: `cmdFlags = {'SID':self._nextSid} )` should be `cmdFlags = {b'SID':self._nextSid} )`

Comment: My bad, I should've seen that.. However: `File "C:/...", line 220, in doFinsCommand
    c = FinsTCPframe(MRC=MRC, SRC=SRC, cmdData = cmdData,  serverAdr=self.serverNode, clientAdr=self.clientNode,  cmdFlags = {b'SID':self._nextSid} )
  File "C:/...", line 93, in __init__
    commandFrame = intlist2str(commandFlags) + cmdData
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str`

Comment: `cmdData = '\x00'` should be `cmdData = b'\x00'`

Comment: Now I feel bad haha, I should've seen that too. New error: `File "C:/, line 270, in readMemC
    memSpec= re.search(b'(.)([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)',mem).groups()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 166, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: can't use a bytes pattern on a string-like object`

Comment: Did you changed `plc.readMemC('D2000', 1)` to `plc.readMemC(b'D2000', 1)`?

Comment: So I have to apply b'...' in main() too? I just did, it works now but another problem: `File "C:/", line 285, in readMemC
    res = [ ord( rawres[i]) * 256 + ord( rawres[ i+1]) for i in range(0,  len(rawres)/2, 2)]
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: Oh I need to apply your workaround i think, edit: nope.

Comment: `len(rawres)/2` should be `len(rawres)//2`

Comment: No more errors!! :D I will test it right now to see if the script works properly!

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your help! When we have our Blender3D simulations running I will show you the result which we wouldn't have accomplished without your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bytes-only operations like `self._send(c1.raw)` needs to be encoded correctly. Use either `self._send(bytes(c1.raw, "utf-8"))` or `self._send(c1.raw.encode("utf-8"))`

   However, since your classes like `FinsTCPframe` is actually operating bytes stream instead of unicode literals, I'd suggest to just stick to bytes (append `b` in front of any affected string constants, like `b''` instead of `''`
2. `ord()` around an item of a `bytes` instance (for example, if `s` is a `bytes` instance, `s[i]` is the item) should be removed, since retrieving one element from bytes in Python 3.x is already a `int` instance. If you are not 100% sure what's inside your ord() call, try this (dirty) workaround:

   `safe_ord = lambda c: ord(c) if isinstance(c, str) else c`

   And replace corresponding `ord()` with `safe_ord()`
3. `chr()` in python 3 returns a `str`, but if you need `bytes` instead, try this:

   `bytes_chr = lambda x: bytes([x])` (from [this stackoverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523505/chr-equivalent-returning-a-bytes-object-in-py3k)

   And replace corresponding `chr()` with `bytes_chr()`
4. Division `/` is resulting in a float by default, so if you want to retain the old behavior, double the symbol: `//`

A full list of porting guide can be found on the [official python docs site](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html), consult this if you need to do the porting work in the future :)