# Python XOR error

Tags: python, python-3.x, xor, bit

So this is a little bit of code that used to work on it's own, but when i tried to implement it into my code it gave me an error, i think it's because i mutated the bits inside of s2 is there any other way to XOR s3 without binascii.a2b_qp

```
def xor(s1,s2):
    s3 =''.join(chr(i^j) for i,j in zip(s1,s2))
    s4 = binascii.a2b_qp(s3)
    s5 = ''.join(chr(i^j) for i,j in zip(s2,s4))
    print(s5)

# for testing:
# additional info, s1 is a mutated form of bits from s2 using an S box
s1 = b'\xc3\xbf\x00\x00\xc3\xbf\x00\xc3\xbf\x00\x00'
s2 = b'aaaaaaaa'
xor(s1, s2)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\Pavilion g7\workspace\Python Network\RW.py", line 138, in <module> 
    x= xor(m1,m2) 
  File "C:\Users\Pavilion g7\workspace\Python Network\RW.py", line 69, in xor 
    s4 = binascii.a2b_qp(s3) 
ValueError: string argument should contain only ASCII characters
```

Comment: What input are you giving it that's triggering this error?

Comment: It's much more helpful if you can show the entire error trace, not just the error message.

Comment: @Newbie Was the code previously on Python 2 and now you're using it on Python 3? The behavior of `chr` changed between the two versions; in Python 3, it returns a `str` (i.e. unicode).

Comment: Wait, in `i^j`, are you xoring two strings? Does that even work?

Comment: nope i'm using python 3 since i started, below is the code i'm using implemented somewhere else

Comment: s1 = b'abc'
s2 = b'ebd'

s3 =''.join(chr(i^j) for i,j in zip(s1,s2))
s4=binascii.a2b_qp(s3)

s5 = ''.join(chr(i^j) for i,j in zip(s4,s2))
print("s5 = ",s5)      >> s5 =  abc

Comment: What's the point of using `binascii.a2b_qp` at the first place? Is the string supposed to contain quoted-printable data?

Comment: BTW, you should have only the one line in your function. The fiddling with the data should happen outside.

Comment: i'm relatively new to python, this is a code i got from stackoverflow to xor a bstring, and if i don't use binascii i end up with this (PS i'm also asking for any substitution for binascii that would run the code):     s5 = ''.join(chr(i^j) for i,j in zip(s2,s3))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was already commented, `chr()` returns a string.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4523505/296974), you get advice about how to replace it.

Similiarly, you should not `.join()` with `''`, the empty string, but with `b''`, the empty bytes object.

Example:

```
def bchr(i):
    return bytes([i])

def xor(s1,s2):
    return b''.join(bchr(i ^ j) for i, j in zip(s1, s2))

s1 = b'\xc3\xbf\x00\x00\xc3\xbf\x00\xc3\xbf\x00\x00'
s2 = b'aaaaaaaa'
s3 = xor(s1, s2)
s4 = binascii.a2b_qp(s3)
s5 = xor(s2, s4)
print(s5)
```

`s5` is still not `s1`, that's because `s2` is too short. Replace it with

```
s2 = b'a' * len(s1)
```

and you are done. It now works as well with

```
s5 = xor(s2, s3)
print(s5 == s1) # -> True
```

thus removing the need for the `binascii` stuff altogether.

Comment: well i'm pretty sure that s1 and s2 have the same number of bits since when i implement the inverse Sbox s1 results in s2

Comment: block = b'aaaaaaaa'
binary = getBin(block)

s1 = initialPerm(binary)
s2 = inversePerm(s1)
m1= bitsToString(s1)
m2= bitsToString(s2)

print(m1)
print(m2)

b'\xc3\xbf\x00\x00\xc3\xbf\x00\xc3\xbf\x00\x00'
b'aaaaaaaa'

Comment: 11 bytes have 88 bits, 8 bytes have 64 bits. I don't know why `s1` is longer than `block`...

Comment: Yeah your method works correctly, my method bitsToString added 3 bytes to my message i don't know how or why but when i switched the chr to bchr in it, it stopped giving that overhead so technically chr ruined 2 methods in my code thanks alot for the help i'm really new to python and i hassled you abit :)