# sending ethernet data along with ARP protocol to automobile gateway in Python

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, compiler-errors

I have programmed in python, where an Array of Bytes will be send to activate a a protocol feature in the automobile Gateway. Basically I am building a lower Level ISO-OSI structure which sends a packet of Ethernet layer along with the ARP protocol structure. I have connected the Raspberry pi 2 to a Gateway via an Ethernet LAN cable. I am using an API in Raspberry to run the code. I am using python 3 to compile.

```
#start of program

from socket import *

 def sendeth(ethernet_packet,payload,interface = "eth0"):
    """Sending RAW Ethernet packets with ARP protocol."""

    s= socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)

    s.bind((interface,0))
    return s.send(ethernet_packet + payload)

def pack(byte_sequence):
    """convert list of bytes to byte string"""
    return b"".join(map(chr, byte_sequence))


if __name__ == "__main__":
#desadd,srcadd,ethtype    
       ethernet_packet= [0x00, 0x36, 0xf8, 0x00, 0x5b, 0xed, 0xb8, 0x27,   0xcb, 0x8c, 0x1c, 0xf9, 0x08, 0x06]  

#arpprotocol
       arp_packet = [0x00, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x06, 0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x1f, 0xaf, 0x57, 0x33, 0xb1, 0xa9, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x36, 0xf8, 0x00, 0x5b, 0xed, 0xa9, 0xfe, 0x3f, 0x29] 

   payload = "".join(map(chr, arp_packet))

r = sendeth(pack(ethernet_packet),
            pack(arp_packet))
printf("sent Etherent with ARP_Paket payload length is %d bytes" % r)
```

When I run the program in my raspberry PI

```
$sudo python3 APR.py
```

it throws an error,

```
Traceback (most recent call test):  
File"APR.py", line 24,in <module>  
r = sendeth(pack(ethernet_packet),  
File"APR.py", line 13,in pack  
return b"".join(map(chr, byte_sequence))  
TypeError: sequence intem 0: expected Bytes, bytearray, or an object with   the buffer Interface, str found.
```

I have tried my Level best in Google and Wikipedia for this plausible error, but wasn't able to find any. I am just a month old in Python. So any leads or help on this issue would be helpful and handy.

*Probable solution*

Since I am using python 3, it throws up an error. Where as in Python 2 its perfectlf fine. May be in python 3 I am not able to send the hexa decimal as strings!! If if this is the Problem can someone help me how to overcome the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your pack() function does not work, as the `chr` function
return `str` but not a byte string. See [chr() equivalent returning a bytes object, in py3k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523505/chr-equivalent-returning-a-bytes-object-in-py3k) for possible solutions.

In your case, the easiest solution is to use `bytearray` directly:

```
r = sendeth(bytearray(ethernet_packet),
        bytearrayarp_packet))
```

Comment: I have already tried with `bytearray` but same error throws up.

Comment: @qwerty I rewrote the answer.