# Python 3 - incorrect decoding ascii symbols (Python 2.7 works well)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, ascii, chr

Via HTTP API I get array of integers, [37,80,68,70,45] - and so on, which represents ascii codes. I need to save it as pdf file. In php code is:

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$pdf_data = implode('', array_map('chr', json_decode($data)));
file_put_contents($file_path.".pdf", $pdf_data);
```

and it works fine.

But, in python 3:

```
http_request_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
data = json.loads(http_request_data)
pdf_data = ''.join(map(chr, data))
with open(file_path, 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(pdf_data)
```

The result pdf file is damaged and can't be read

What can be the problem?

EDIT:

Tried with python 2.7, file opens and it's good. Problem not solved, I need it in python 3.6

EDIT:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25839524/7451009 - this solution is ok!

Comment: hard to answer without checking the data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it works in Python2 and not in Python3, the hint is that it is probably caused by a byte vs unicode problem.

Strings and characters are bytes in Python2 and unicode in Python3. If your code works in Python2, its Python3 equivalent should be:

```
http_request_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
data = json.loads(http_request_data)
pdf_data = bytes(data)                 # construct a bytes string
with open(file_path, 'wb') as fout:    # file must be opened in binary mode
    fout.write(pdf_data)
```

Comment: Yes, when opened with python 2, i got the idea, then "googled" this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25839524/7451009 . Thank you very much for the reply!